# Parsing xml file with SAX parser

Tags: java, xml

my handler class:

```
   package csc241hw06;


        import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.time.LocalDateTime;
        import java.time.ZoneOffset;

        import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
        import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
        import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

        /**
         * Created by Dan1 on 3/9/2017.
         */
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private Customer customer;
    private Account account;
    private Address address;
    private Meter meter;
    private MeterReading meterReading;
    private ArrayList <Customer> customerArrayList;
    private ArrayList <Address> addressList;

    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    String addressType;
    String accountNum;
    String accountType;

    public MyHandler() {
        customerArrayList = new ArrayList <Customer> ();
        addressList = new ArrayList <Address> ();
    }

    public ArrayList <Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerArrayList;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "Customer" ) ) {
            lastName = attributes.getValue ( "lastName" );
            firstName = attributes.getValue ( "firstName" );

        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "account" ) ) {
            accountType = attributes.getValue ( "type" );
            accountNum = attributes.getValue ( "accountNumber" );
            if ( accountType.equalsIgnoreCase ( "residential" ) ) {
                account = new ResidentialAccount ( accountNum, customer );
            } else {
                account = new CommercialAccount ( accountNum, customer );
            }
        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "address" ) ) {
            String unit = attributes.getValue ( "unit" );
            String street = attributes.getValue ( "street" );
            String number = attributes.getValue ( "number" );
            String zipCode = attributes.getValue ( "zipCode" );
            int parseNum = Integer.parseInt ( number );

            if ( attributes.getValue ( "type" ).equals ( "mailing" ) ) {
                if ( attributes.getValue ( "unit" ) == null ) {


                    if ( accountType.equalsIgnoreCase ( "residential" ) ) {
                        address = new Residence ( parseNum, street, zipCode );
                    } else {
                        address = new Commercial ( parseNum, street, zipCode );

                    }


                } else {
                    address = new Apartment ( parseNum, street, zipCode, unit );
                }
                if ( customer == null ) {
                    customer = new Customer ( lastName, firstName, address );
                }

            } else if ( attributes.getValue ( "type" ).equalsIgnoreCase ( "apartment" ) ) {
                address = new Apartment ( parseNum, street, zipCode, unit );


            } else if ( attributes.getValue ( "type" ).equalsIgnoreCase ( "commercial" ) ) {
                address = new Commercial ( parseNum, street, zipCode );
            } else if ( attributes.getValue ( "type" ).equalsIgnoreCase ( "house" ) ) {
                address = new Residence ( parseNum, street, zipCode );
            }


        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "meter" ) ) {
            String id = attributes.getValue ( "id" );
            String brand = attributes.getValue ( "brand" );
            String meterType = attributes.getValue ( "type" );
            String location = attributes.getValue ( "location" );

            if ( meterType.equalsIgnoreCase ( "push" ) ) {
                meter = new PushMeter ( id, brand );
            } else if ( meterType.equalsIgnoreCase ( "poll" ) ) {
                meter = new PollMeter ( id, brand );
            }
            meter.setLocation ( address, location );


        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "meterReading" ) ) {
            String reading = attributes.getValue ( "reading" );

            String date = attributes.getValue ( "date" );
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" );
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse ( date, formatter );

            String flag = attributes.getValue ( "flag" );

            meterReading = new MeterReading ( Double.parseDouble ( reading ), dateTime, flag, meter );
        }

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "customer" ) ) {
            customerArrayList.add ( customer );
        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "account" ) ) {
            customer.addAccount ( account );
            account.updateBalance ();
        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "address" ) ) {


            addressList.add ( address );


            for (int i = 0; i < addressList.size (); i++) {
                account.addAddress ( addressList.get ( i ) );
            }


            addressList = new ArrayList <Address> ();


        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "meter" ) ) {
            address.addMeter ( meter );
        } else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase ( "meterReading" ) ) {
            meter.addReading ( meterReading );
        }
    }


}
```

my xml file:

```
    <customer lastName ="Adams" firstName="Maurice">
        <address type="mailing" unit="308" street="W 4th St." number="56" zipCode="13126"/>
        <account type="residential" accountNumber="876-543-21">
            <address type="apartment" unit="308" street="W 4th St." number="56" zipCode="13126">


                <meter id = "RM-4877-X4" brand="GE" type="push" location = "East side of building">

                    <meterReading reading="650" date = "2016-12-31T00:31" flag="push"/>
                    <meterReading reading="675" date = "2017-01-01T00:37" flag="push"/>
                    <meterReading reading="622" date = "2017-01-02T00:38" flag="push"/>
                </meter>      
            </address>
        </account>     
    </customer>


    <customer lastName ="Costanza" firstName="George">
        <address type="mailing" street="E 5th St." number="65" zipCode="13126"/>
        <account type="commercial" accountNumber="765-432-10">
            <address type="commercial" street="Albany St." number="56" zipCode="13126">
                <meter id = "CM-7784-D1" brand="GE" type="poll" location = "North entrance">
                    <meterReading reading="5043" date = "2016-12-31T00:32" flag="poll"/>
                    <meterReading reading="6152" date = "2017-01-01T00:38" flag="poll"/>
                    <meterReading reading="7261" date = "2017-01-02T00:41" flag="poll"/>
                </meter>      
            </address>
            <address type="commercial" street="Oneida St." number="72" zipCode="13126">
                <meter id = "CM-7684-D2" brand="GE" type="push" location = "South end of basement">
                    <meterReading reading="650" date = "2016-12-31T00:21" flag="push"/>
                    <meterReading reading="760" date = "2017-01-01T00:23" flag="push"/>
                    <meterReading reading="781" date = "2017-01-02T00:25" flag="push"/>
                    <meterReading reading="722" date = "2017-01-03T00:27" flag="push"/>
                </meter>      
            </address>
        </account>     
    </customer>
</xml>
```

the problem is that every time I try to add an address to my address list it returns an error in the endElement method. Yes this is a homework assignment, I have tried everything and don't have any idea who else to ask (my teacher isn't much help at the moment) any help would be very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Don't just tell us it "returns an error". Tell us exactly how it fails.

Comment: corrected typos.

Comment: You've made it very difficult for us to help you here.  As has already been noted, you haven't told us what the error that's being returned is.  We might be able to find it ourselves if only we could compile your code, but if we wanted to do that we'd have to write all of the classes you are using (`Customer`, `Address`, `Meter`, `Apartment` etc.) along with all of the methods they need.  Do you expect us to do that?  And who's to say the error you're encountering isn't a bug in one of those classes you've chosen not to share with us?